# Ideas About Sorting Path?

Tags: java, coordinates, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to sort a list of points into a path by proximity, but the only way I can think of to do this is by iterating them and getting the absolute value distance between the current stored item and the item I'm iterating over, then make that point current if the absolute value of the difference between the new coordinate and the current coordinate is more than 0 but not more than 2 (finding adjacent coordinates).

However, I have a scope problem, and I'm scratching my head on what to do here. I'm not sorting them by increasing x, y, or z value - right now, I'm testing with a radius of 1 - so more traditional sorting approaches wouldn't work here.

Does anybody have any pointers?

```
package pickquest.common;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.Location;

public class Path {
    private HashMap<Integer, Location> pathSequence = new HashMap<>();

    public HashMap<Integer, Location> getPathSequence() {
        return pathSequence;
    }

    public void setPathSequence(HashMap<Integer, Location> pathSequence) {
        this.pathSequence = pathSequence;
    }

    public void setsequencePath(Location origin, ArrayList<Location> points, Location destination) {
        sequencePath(origin, points, destination);
    }

    private void sequencePath(Location origin, ArrayList<Location> points, Location destination) {
        Location current = origin;
        ArrayList<Location> processedPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        processedPoints.addAll(points);
        while (!(processedPoints.isEmpty())) {
            Integer index = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {

                if ((Math.abs(current.getX() - processedPoints.get(i).getX()) > 0) && (Math.abs(current.getX() - processedPoints.get(i).getX()) <= 1.9)) {
                    if (!(pathSequence.containsValue(processedPoints.get(i)))) {
                        getPathSequence().put(index, processedPoints.get(i));
                        processedPoints.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                } else if ((Math.abs(current.getY() - processedPoints.get(i).getY()) > 0) && (Math.abs(current.getY() - processedPoints.get(i).getY()) <= 1.9)) {
                    if (!(pathSequence.containsValue(processedPoints.get(i)))) {
                        getPathSequence().put(index, processedPoints.get(i));
                        processedPoints.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                } else if ((Math.abs(current.getY() - processedPoints.get(i).getY()) > 0) && (Math.abs(current.getY() - processedPoints.get(i).getY()) <= 1.9)) {
                    if (!(pathSequence.containsValue(processedPoints.get(i)))) {
                        getPathSequence().put(index, processedPoints.get(i));
                        processedPoints.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                processedPoints.remove(i);
                index++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < pathSequence.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + pathSequence.get(i));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I believe a common approach would be to use the absolute distance.. (√ (distX² + distY² + distZ²) where distXYZ are the distance between your current position and the next position on each axis. Asking this on Math.SE would probably be a good idea since questions like that occur pretty often ("traveling salesman" for example, but that's for two dimensional coord systems).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a TreeMap and sort your locations according to the distance, then use TreeMap's heading/tailing functionality. e.g.:

```
public class Path {

    private final Iterable<Location> points;
    public Path(Iterable<Location> points) {
        this.points= points;
    }

    public TreeMap<Double, Location> getNearby(Location from) {
        TreeMap<Double, Location> nearby = new TreeMap<>();
        for (Location point: points) {
            nearby.put(distance(point, from), point);
        }
        return nearby;
    }

    public SortedMap<Double, Location> getNearby(Location from, double maxDistance) {
        return getNearby(from).headMap(maxDistance);
    }

    private static double distance(Location o1, Location o2) {
        double a = o1.getX() - o2.getX();
        double b = o1.getY() - o2.getY();
        double c = o1.getZ() - o2.getZ();
        return Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b + c * c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into TreeMaps and SortedMaps a bit later on. I'm still becoming familiar with a lot of aspects of the Java Collections Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I've basically figured this out now. There are probably simpler ways of doing it, and I'll want more specific contingency systems, but for what I wanted, which is sorting a 1-block radius around a player, this works.

Later on, I'll add some sort of weighted system, accounting for the distance between the x, y, and z points, and generally favoring certain actions accordingly. There may be a lot of unnecessary code that doesn't do anything at this point. Some things are declared twice - once at the beginning, and once at the end. I'll clean it up a bit more later.

```
package pickquest.common;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import org.bukkit.Location;

public class Path {
 private HashMap<Integer, Location> pathSequence = new HashMap<>(); 

 public HashMap<Integer, Location> getPathSequence() {
    return pathSequence;
}

 public void setPathSequence(HashMap<Integer, Location> pathSequence) {
    this.pathSequence = pathSequence;
}
 public void setsequencePath(Location origin, ArrayList<Location> points, Location destination) {
    sequencePath(origin, points, destination);
}

 private HashMap<Integer, Location> sequencePath(Location origin, ArrayList<Location> points, Location destination) {
    Location current = origin;
    ArrayList<Location> processedPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    processedPoints.addAll(points);
    ListIterator<Location> pointsIterator = processedPoints.listIterator();
    Integer index = 0;
    Location loc = origin;
    int counter = 0;
    while(pointsIterator.hasNext()) {
        loc=pointsIterator.next();
        if(!(pathSequence.isEmpty())) {
            current = pathSequence.get(pathSequence.size()-1);
        }
        else if(pathSequence.isEmpty()) {
            current= origin;
        }

        if(Math.abs(current.getX() - loc.getX()) > 0 && (Math.abs(current.getX() - loc.getX())) <= 1.3 && (Math.abs(current.getY() - loc.getY())) >= 0 && (Math.abs(current.getY() - loc.getY())) < 1 && (Math.abs(current.getZ() - loc.getZ())) >= 0 && (Math.abs(current.getZ() - loc.getZ())) < 1) { 
            pathSequence.put(index, loc);
            pointsIterator.remove();
            index++;

        }
        else if( ( (Math.abs(current.getY() - loc.getY())) > 0 && (Math.abs(current.getY() - loc.getY())) <= 1.3) && (Math.abs(current.getZ() - loc.getZ())) >= 0 && (Math.abs(current.getZ() - loc.getZ())) < 1 && (Math.abs(current.getX() - loc.getX())) >= 0 && (Math.abs(current.getX() - loc.getX())) < 1) {
            pathSequence.put(index, loc);
            pointsIterator.remove();
            index++;

        }
        else if(Math.abs(current.getZ() - loc.getZ()) > 0 && (Math.abs(current.getZ() - loc.getZ())) <= 1.3 && (Math.abs(current.getY() - loc.getY())) >= 0 && (Math.abs(current.getY() - loc.getY())) < 1 && (Math.abs(current.getX() - loc.getX())) >= 0 && (Math.abs(current.getX() - loc.getX())) < 1) {
            pathSequence.put(index, loc);
            pointsIterator.remove();
            index++;

        }
        if(!(pathSequence.isEmpty())) {
            current = pathSequence.get(pathSequence.size()-1);
        }

        if(!(pointsIterator.hasNext()) && !(processedPoints.isEmpty())) {

            System.out.println("reset fired");
            counter++;

            if(processedPoints.size() == 1) {
                pathSequence.put(index, loc);
            }
            if(pointsIterator.hasPrevious()) {
            int i = processedPoints.size() - 1;

                    Collections.swap(processedPoints, (processedPoints.size() -1 ), i );
                    if(!(pathSequence.isEmpty())) {
                        current = pathSequence.get(pathSequence.size()-1);
                    }
                    while(pointsIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                        pointsIterator.previous();
                    }
                }
            }
        System.out.println(processedPoints.size()); 

        if(counter > 250) {
            break;

        }
            }
    return pathSequence;
}
```

}